# proving that a ring is not semisimple

Tags: abstract-algebra, semi-simple-rings

proving that a ring is not semisimple.

A question asks me explicitly that the ring of matrices

$M_{a,b}=\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ 0 & a \end{pmatrix}$ is not semisimple by showing that the submodule $M_{0, b}$ doesn't have a complement.

I proceed as follows.

Assume $M_{a,b}= M_{0, b} \oplus P$  where $P$ is an
$M_{a,b}$-submodule.
Choose any element from $M_{a,b}$, say $$\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ 0  & a \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & c \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$
where $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & b \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}\in M_{0,b}$. Then $$\begin{pmatrix} a & b-c\\ 0 & a \end{pmatrix} \in 0$$  and since $P$ is an ideal implies

$$\begin{pmatrix} -1 & 1\\0 & -1  \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} a & b-c \\ 0 &  a \end{pmatrix} =\begin{pmatrix} -a & b-c+a\\0 & -a \end{pmatrix}\in P$$

Thus $$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 2b-2c+a\\0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} a & b-c \\ 0 & a \end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix} -a & b-c+a \\ 0 & -a \end{pmatrix} \in P$$

Thus $M_{0,b} \cap P \neq 0$ which is a contradiction.
Does this look correct?

Comment: You claimed that an arbitrary element of $M_{a,b}$ is of the form $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & c \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$, which is false.

Comment: @diracdeltafunk, nope I am not sure where I did that

Comment: The second sentence in your proof reads "Choose any element from $M_{a,b}$, say $$\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ 0  & a \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & c \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$"

Comment: well, I am trying to express an element of $M_{a,b}$ as sum and reach at a contradiction.  I had choosen that element because it was convenient to deal with and it was natural. I don't see an issue with selecting an element from the set

Comment: You can certainly select an element from $M_{a,b}$. An arbitrary element would look like $\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ 0 & a \end{pmatrix}$. However, you may not assume that this element is equal to $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & c \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ for some $c$.

Comment: I also want to point out that nowhere in this proof attempt did you use the assumption that $M_{a,b} = M_{0,b} + P$. You must use this in order to get a contradiction! Moreover, you can't deduce $M_{0,b} \cap P \neq 0$ from your last equation unless $2b-2c+a \neq 0$.

Comment: @diracdeltafunk, alright then how should I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Of course, as a vector space, $M_{0,b}$ does have a complement! Namely, $M_{a,0}$. However, $M_{a,0}$ is not an ideal. Why not? Because $M_{a,0}$ contains the identity matrix, but $M_{a,0}$ is not equal to the entire ring $M_{a,b}$.

$M_{a,0}$ is not the only complement of $M_{0,b}$ as a vector subspace of $M_{a,b}$, but we can try to extend this reasoning to see that $M_{0,b}$ has no complementary ideal whatsoever.

---

As you suggested, we should start by supposing for contradiction that $M_{a,b} = M_{0,b} \oplus P$ for some ideal $P \trianglelefteq M_{a,b}$. Now the identity matrix $1 \in M_{a,b}$ can be written as $$1 = X + Y$$
for some $X \in M_{0,b}$ and $Y \in P$. Write $X = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & x \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$. Then $Y = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & -x \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$. Now since $Y \in P$ and $P$ is an ideal, we have
$$1 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & x \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}Y \in P.$$
Then, since $P$ is an ideal, $P = M_{a,b}$. Now
$$M_{0,b} = M_{0,b} \cap M_{a,b} = M_{0,b} \cap P = 0,$$
contradiction!